# why does my code which takes fasta formated DNA and transforms it into a vector crashes on run

Tags: c++, bioinformatics

I compiled both in code blocks and cygwin but it crashes when i run it.
The source.txt file is formated like this:

>sample1
ACTG
GCA
GTC
>sample2
TAACG
GGCC
And dtb should look something like this:
dtb=(sample1,ACTGGCAGTC,sample2,TAACGGGCC)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    int i=0;
    string seq="",holder="";
    myfile.open("source.txt");
    vector<string> dtb;
    while (myfile>> seq)
    {
        if (seq.substr(0,1)==">")
        {
            dtb[i]=seq.substr(1,seq.length()-1);
            i++;
            if (i!=0)
                dtb[i]=holder;
            holder="";
        }
        else
        {
            holder+=seq;
        }
    }
    cout<<dtb[0]<<"\n"<<dtb[1]<<"\n"<<dtb[2]<<"\n"<<dtb[3];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) object starts out empty. That means any indexing in it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

You need to *add* elements to the vector, using e.g. [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).